# DDB unknown file

Tags: sqlite, dll

I have a .ddb file that is used as a telephone directory for an application written in flash/VB.net (i guess). The problem is that the application is crashing and my only was to access the application is through the mysterious (*.ddb) file (99% of the application size.)

The application contains an also mysterious dll (NK_SQLite.dll).

So far I have tried:

- SQLite Browser
- tried opening the file in PL/SQL
- tried opening the file in SQL Server

Any ideas about how to solve this issue,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it possible that the DDB extension is misleading? Have you tried opening it as a CAB or ZIP file? The NK_SQLLite.dll file certainly makes it sound like a SQLLite database but again it could be a red herring.

Another possibility... if any of the code is .NET, have you tried disassembling it? You might get some hints about what's going on that way, so long as it's not obfuscated. If you're unfamiliar with how to do that, I would recommend a tool like RedGate's Reflector (http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector)

Comment: I have tried the CAB and the ZIP through 7-zip and win-rar, but no luck. I also tried opening the file with PSPad but it turns out that the file is binary.

Regarding the RedGate sortware, it appears that the file (.exe) is having an error on all versions of the .net Assembly versions provided.
Is there a way to find out which assembly version this file was created with?

Comment: I'm afraid if Reflector can't figure out the executable, then I don't know of a way to find out what version was used. It seems most likely that the application is either not built in .NET, or has been obfuscated so it can't be reverse engineered.

I'm not sure what else to suggest at this point... That storage file in might not be any real database at all; it could be a custom format designed specifically for the application in question.

Hopefully someone else can come up with some suggestions.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I appreciate the concern.

I'll keep this post open in case i found something relevant.